# What's wrong with my recursion? Trying to add two node in each traversal

Tags: java, data-structures

Seems like my linear linked list didn't connect for each recursion. Need explanation why my code doesn't work.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */


public class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        if(l1 == null)
            return null;
        int val = l1.val + l2.val;
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(val);
        System.out.println(newNode.val);
        return newNode.next = addTwoNumbers(l1.next, l2.next);
    }
}
```

Your input

[2,4,3]
[5,6,4]

Your stdout

7
10
7

Your answer

[]

Expected answer

[7,10,7]

Comment: With all due respect you don't need us for this exercise.  Run your code under debugger and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you didn't return *newNode.next*.
You must call recursion method with newNode.next but you must return **newNode**. 
Ps. Remember to add `if (l2==null) return null;`

Comment: I did return the newNode.

Comment: @MikeNguyen if you return newNode it seems that you don't have any problem

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return newNode.next = addTwoNumbers(l1.next, l2.next);
```

To

```
newNode.next = addTwoNumbers(l1.next, l2.next);
return newNode
```